# OCR by setting font

Tags: ocr, handwriting-recognition

I have some images which have fonts like Lucida Handwriting. Since those are cursive my OCR Software doesn't recognize them correctly.
Is there a way to let the software to know that the fonts in images are similar to Lucida Handwriting?
If we let to know that will the software refer letters from the given font category to read images correctly?